# NullPointerException on not earlier used Emulator [ListView Adapter]

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception, size, adapter

So I've been trying to make an app. It works all fine on the NEXUS 5X Emulator, but when I try running it on the Pixel C (and my own real life phone) it crashes.

I think it has something to do with the fact that the NEXUS 5X Emulator has already 3 players. The other devices don't. (I tried hardcoding some players but that crashed)

This is the crash I've been getting:

```
2020-06-29 23:45:32.926 13211-13211/com.example.drinkdrankdrunk E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.drinkdrankdrunk, PID: 13211
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.drinkdrankdrunk/com.example.drinkdrankdrunk.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:380)
    at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:575)
    at com.example.drinkdrankdrunk.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

It crashes on this rule:

```
playersListView.setAdapter(playersAdapter);
```

This is some of my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    admin = new Admin();

    admin.addPlayer("Test");



    loadData();

    // Zorg ervoor dat het toetsenbord niet automatisch wordt geopend
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

    // Players List View
    playersListView = findViewById(R.id.playersListView);
    PlayersAdapter playersAdapter = new PlayersAdapter(this, admin.getPlayers());
    playersListView.setAdapter(playersAdapter);

    // Refresh List View
    refreshPlayersAdapter = playersAdapter;

    // Add player
    addPlayerButton = findViewById(R.id.addPlayerButton);
    addPlayerEditText = findViewById(R.id.addPlayerEditText);

    // Play Button
    playButton = findViewById(R.id.playButton);
}
```

admin.getPlayers() gives this:

```
public class PlayersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Player> {
private LayoutInflater Inflater;
Admin admin = new Admin();


public PlayersAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull List<Player> objects) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_players, objects);

    Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
   if (convertView == null) {
       convertView = Inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_players, parent, false);
   }

    TextView playerNameTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.playerNameTextView);
    ImageView deleteButtonImageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.deleteButtonImageView);

    Player player = getItem(position);

    playerNameTextView.setText(player.getNamePlayer());

    // Delete button
    deleteButtonImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            admin.getPlayers().remove(position);
            // Refresh scherm
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

}

I hope someone can help me out.

X

Comment: Can you add the complete error stack trace and the code of the adapter class?

Comment: Added! @EraftYps